# How to compare the accuracy of predictive algorithms when the predicted value contains measurement error

Tags: time-series, correlation, predictive-models, model-selection, measurement-error

I am conducting (somewhat casual) research on the accuracy of several algorithms meant to compute a value when given a set of experimentally gathered variables, including time. The issue is, the true value is not available to me, and I have no way of experimentally determining it. Is there some way of quantitatively comparing the predictions of several algorithms without an empirical value to which to compare? I feel tremendously naked without any sort of error analysis.

I considered displaying the correlation between the various results relative to one another, but this seems to be an inappropriate usage of correlation - obviously the results are related, as they use many of the same variables.

An analogy for clarity: Say I have four algorithms that predict how tall a tree will grow based on a variety of variables, like the species of the tree, the chemical content of the soil, the latitude, longitude, mean temperature of the environment, etc. These all use slightly different variables and produce different results, because they're based on different research. So an experiment is performed, the characteristics that the algorithms use are measured, and the trees are grown. This is where my analogy breaks down, because in my case the issue is that the height of the tree *cannot be quantitatively measured.* I cannot, therefore, compare the predictions of the algorithms with reality - I can tell if they're reasonable, based on common sense and their order of magnitude, but I cannot calculate accuracy. Are there any quantitative methods that can be used in this case?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to predict the value of a *response variable* based on other variables, 1 of which is time? What do you mean that "the true value is not available"? Do you mean that there is *measurement error* in the predicted variable, or do you mean that you will use these algorithms in the future & you won't know the values then, or something else?

Comment: I'll do an edit for clarity.

Comment: OK, it's primarily the 2nd question that I'm wondering about.

Comment: Hmmm, that's an unusual scenario. I gather the height of a tree isn't the actual variable you want to predict; that could be measured. Can you state what the actual variable *is*? The more details we have, the more likely someone will be able to provide helpful advice.

Comment: I added the analogy for clarity, but to respond more directly to your question, I want to *compare* the response variables produced by a variety of algorithms given a common set of manipulated variables (one of which is time). There is measurement error in the predicted variable, because it is a mathematical estimation of a natural process.

Comment: I am hesitant to go into too much detail around the experiment due to the nature of my nondisclosure agreement. Suffice to say the algorithms are simple mathematical models to predict the end result of a complex biological process. And thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Is it possible to make a reasonable guess at the distribution of the measurement error? Eg, would it be normal, or at least symmetrical around the true value?

Comment: Well, the error in the measurements that I've made myself and run through the equations is predictable. The issue in my mind is that the equations are not true representations of the process, and error will be introduced by their very nature. Say I have an equation that predicts the size of a cricket based on the volume of its chirping. I can tell you what the distribution of the measurement error in the volume is, in decibels, but the equation itself is a poor representation of a process based on many, many other variables, and the error inherent in using the formula at all is unclear.